# makefile execute another target

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile structured something like this:

```
all : 
    compile executable

clean :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
```

I realized that I was consistently running "make clean" followed by "clear" in my terminal before running "make all". I like to have a clean terminal before I try and sift through nasty C++ compilation errors. So I tried to add a 3rd target:

```
fresh :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
    clear
    make all
```

This works, however this runs a second instance of make (I believe). Is there a right way to get the same functionality without running a 2nd instance of make?

Comment: I'm not sure if this shouldn't be a separate question, but why is it bad to call nested make commands?

Answer (score 283, accepted):

Actually you are right: it runs another instance of make.
A possible solution would be:

```sh
.PHONY : clearscr fresh clean all

all :
    compile executable

clean :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)

fresh : clean clearscr all

clearscr:
    clear
```

By calling `make fresh` you get first the `clean` target, then the `clearscreen` which runs `clear` and finally `all` which does the job.

**EDIT Aug 4**

What happens in the case of parallel builds with make’s `-j` option?
There's a way of fixing the order. From the make manual, section 4.2:

> Occasionally, however, you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked without forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define order-only prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only: targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
>
> The normal prerequisites section may of course be empty. Also, you may still declare multiple lines of prerequisites for the same target: they are appended appropriately. Note that if you declare the same file to be both a normal and an order-only prerequisite, the normal prerequisite takes precedence (since they are a strict superset of the behavior of an order-only prerequisite).

Hence the makefile becomes

```sh
.PHONY : clearscr fresh clean all

all :
    compile executable

clean :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)

fresh : | clean clearscr all

clearscr:
    clear
```

**EDIT Dec 5**

It is not a big deal to run more than one makefile instance since each command inside the task will be a [sub-shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html#Execution) anyways. But you can have reusable methods using the [call function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html).

```sh
log_success = (echo "\x1B[32m>> $1\x1B[39m")
log_error = (>&2 echo "\x1B[31m>> $1\x1B[39m" && exit 1)

install:
  @[ "$(AWS_PROFILE)" ] || $(call log_error, "AWS_PROFILE not set!")
  command1  # this line will be a subshell
  command2  # this line will be another subshell
  @command3  # Use `@` to hide the command line
  $(call log_error, "It works, yey!")

uninstall:
  @[ "$(AWS_PROFILE)" ] || $(call log_error, "AWS_PROFILE not set!")
  ....
  $(call log_error, "Nuked!")
```

Comment: @sas4740: basically everything follows `.PHONY : ` is treated as some keyword that gets always executed, while non-phony targets are intended to be files.

Comment: are "Order-only prerequisites" conditional?
for target t2 I want first do t0, than only if t0 succeds run t1, and only if both succeds run some task in t3

Comment: @fantastory, no, I **think** they are independent. `t2` will depend on `t0`, `t1` and `t3`. If you need this you should put  `t3` as required by `t2`, `t1` as required by `t3` and `t0` as required by `t1`. This means 3 different rules. You should verify this, however. I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: "Order-only prerequisites" are independent

Comment: I don't see where is the guarantee that 'clean' performs before 'all'? The fact that you put them right from | does not make them execute in-order. Order-only dependency means that target is not necessairly updated after such operation. It has nothing to do with ordering of the dependent elements... or?

Comment: You are right @CygnusX1, order-only dependencies have nothing to do with executing dependencies in a certain order; only with ordering the dependency before the target that references it. The `EDIT Aug 4` part of this answer is wrong.

Comment: Ugh! this breaks parallel _make_. Parallel operation is kinda the whole point of _make_.

Answer (score 24):

You already have a sequential solution which could be rewritten as:

```
fresh:
    $(MAKE) clean
    clear
    $(MAKE) all
```

This is correct and a very safe approach.

Sequential target execution is possible in GNU make with a proper dependency graph:

```
fresh: _all
_all: _clear
    Recipe for all
_clear: _clean
    Recipe for clear
_clean:
    Recipe for clean
```

The above rules define the following dependency graph: `fresh` <- `_all` <- `_clear` <- `_clean` which guarantees the following recipe execution order: `Recipe for clean`, `Recipe for clear`, `Recipe for all`.

Recipes can be shared with multiple targets using:

```
target1 target2 target…:
    recipe1
```

Merging your script with the above concepts results in:

```
all _all : 
    compile executable
clean _clean :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
clear _clear :
    clear
fresh: _all
_all: _clear
_clear: _clean
```

With syntactic sugar using `chains.mk` from https://github.com/pkoper/mk/ you can write:

```
all all@fresh :
    compile executable
clean clean@fresh :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
clear clear@fresh :
    clear

@fresh = clean clear all
include chains.mk

fresh: @fresh
```

Or better:

```
all: compile

@fresh = clean clear compile
include chains.mk

fresh: @fresh

compile compile@fresh:
    compile executable
clear clear@fresh:
    clear
clean clean@fresh:
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you removed the `make all` line from your "fresh" target:

```
fresh :
    rm -f *.o $(EXEC)
    clear
```

You could simply run the command `make fresh all`, which will execute as `make fresh; make all`.

Some might consider this as a second instance of make, but it's certainly not a sub-instance of make (a make inside of a make), which is what your attempt seemed to result in.

Comment: `make -j12 fresh all` fails though. Do not break parallel make!