# Error in calling one make target from another

Tags: unix, makefile, hp-ux

$make --- Will have normal build

$make CAdvisor
Above will do following steps:

1) Update variable `CC`, now it should become `"cadvise -pdb mypdb +wlint +wall aCC"`

2) Run `all` with updated CC option

```
CC = aCC
CFLAGS  = -c #-Wall
LDFLAGS =
SOURCES = foo.cc
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cc=.o)
EXECUTABLE = observer
RM=rm -rf
CADVISE_OPTS= -pdb mypdb +wlint
CADVISE= /opt/cadvise/bin/cadvise

.PHONY : CAdvisor update_cc clean all

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
.cc.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS)

update_cc: CC := ${$(CADVISE) $(CADVISE_OPTS) $(CC)}

CAdvisor: update_cc all;
    @echo DEBD $(CC)
```

Now above code is giving me error:

```
**$ make CAdvisor
Make: Don't know how to make CC.  Stop.
$**
```

- How to fix this error
- Any better option?
  Linkes:[link_how to call target from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267145/makefile-execute-another-target/3267187#3267187)

Thanks

Comment: What version of make are you using?

Comment: $ `swlist -a revision -a title | grep make`
 **3.82           make**
$

Comment: Running `make --version` is a lot faster :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but that's not how target-specific variables work.  Target-specific variables are scoped to their target and any *prerequisite* built as a result of building that target.  It's not the case that the target-specific setting changes the value of the *global* variable for the rest of the recipes expanded by make.

In your example, `all` is not a prerequisite of `update_cc`, it's a sibling.  So, target-specific variables that are set for `update_cc` have no impact on the `all` target.

Second, using `${$(CADVISE) $(CADVISE_OPTS) $(CC)}` is definitely not right: the inside will be expanded first then because the entire thing is enclosed in `${...}` it will be treated as a variable *name*, and that variable (which clearly doesn't exist) will be looked up, resulting in an empty string.

I don't know why you have added the extra target `update_cc` at all; why not just set the target-specific variable on the `CAdvisor` target?

```
CAdvisor: CC := $(CADVISE) $(CADVISE_OPTS) $(CC)

CAdvisor: all
        @echo DEBD $(CC)
```